# How to setup magento 2.1 from existing project

Tags: magento2, environment-emulation

I have an existing project from my personal project repository. What I would like to do is clone this repository and setup the environment, and this is what I have done :

- Installing php 7.0 and all the require extension.
- Install mysql
- install apache2
- Set the sites-available for magento 2. and restart the apache2

now I have the project in my dir `/var/www/html/myproject/`. 
But I don't know where to go from this like, where is the setup for mysql credential ? and other setup to make the project up and running in my local environtment.

Right now when I got to my `localhost` I got `HTTP ERROR 500` ? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I'm able to do this on my own so here is the steps Note I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 for my local env :

1. Make sure all the file permission is your user : `sudo chown -R you-user:your-user .`
2. Create your database schema. You can do this via cli or mysqlbranch.
3. Edit your app/etc/env.php and find these file :

   ```
   array (
   'host' => 'localhost',
   'dbname' => 'yourdatabase',
   'username' => 'root',
   'password' => 'root',
   'model' => 'mysql4',
   'engine' => 'innodb',
   'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
   'active' => '1',
   )
   ```
4. Now make `bin/magento` executable `sudo chmod +x bin/magento`
5. This is **IMPORTANT STEP** : disable your additional module first, and there will only magento **original module** only to feed and setup the database. You can first move all your module first out of the `app/code` and `app/design`.
6. run `bin/magento setup:install --admin-user="gujarat" --admin-password="wkwkwkw" --admin-email="gujarat@balala.com" --admin-firstname="gujarat" --admin-lastname="santana"`. **This will take forever to install**.
7. `bin/magento setup:upgrade`. If you have trouble in this step, this is more likely because of your `custom module` move all your custom module first to another directory and run this command again.
8. `bin/magento setup:di:compile`
9. Set appropriate permission files and folder.

You should see your sites now, but don't forget to move all your `custum module` to its respected directory. And run the upgrade and compile command from 7 & 8 step.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps to setup existing magento 2 project.

1. Import Database : Import the database by using this command. `mysql -u [username] -p newdatabase < [database name].sql;`
2. Clone/Extract the Source code.
3. Run Composer Install Or Composer Update Command : Run the `composer update` command, If composer is not installed then run first `composer install` & then `composer update` command. (If you get any memory limit error then run `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update`)
4. Create `env.php` file : `php bin/magento setup:config:set --db-user="dbusername" --db-password="dbpassword" --db-name="dbname"` or add any existing env.php file and update the host, dbname, username & password.
5. Create `config.php` file : `php bin/magento module:enable --all`
6. Run the following commands one by one :

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

7. Change the base url in database : Table name : `core_config_data`

`path : web/unsecure/base_url`
`path : web/secure/base_url`

Or you can change by using below commands.

`php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/magento/"`

`php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="http://127.0.0.1/magento/"`

Ex: `http://127.0.0.1/magento/`

8. Clean and Flush the cache : `php bin/magento cache:clean` and `php bin/magento cache:flush`.
9. Now open url in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Magento root `app/etc/env.php` set database

```
'host' => 'localhost',
    'dbname' => 'yourdatabasename',
    'username' => 'mysqlusername',
    'password' => 'mysqlpassword',
    'active' => '1',
)
```

also check what is the mode you are `'MAGE_MODE' => 'default'`

clear `/var/cache , /var/generate, var/page_cache`

Enable `app/boostrap.php  - ini_set('display_errors', 1);` check what is 500 error.

**Mysql Export via command line.**

```
mysqldump -u username -p database_name > database_name.sql
```

**Mysql import via command line.**

```
mysql u -username -p database_name < database_name.sql
```

Another important point:

First update both the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` URLs in `core_config_data`

Comment: how to install and import all the tables to the database ? any command or step for that  thanks ?

Comment: i updated the ans. please check it.

Comment: is there any way to install the db from beginning without export from mysql ? like for example when installing magento from the fresh installation ?