# Magneto 2 project on new VPS loading wrong design

Tags: magento2

I have successfully installed my magneto 2 version 2.3.3 project on my new vps service using Ubuntu with php 7.3.13. 
But the design seems to have failed to load correctly. It's all over the place. And images seem to be missing. 
My site also displays the "Default welcome message" in the top navigation bar. Any idéas thanks?

I have set up my database and added the correct information in app/etc/env.php
Using these instructions:

- [How to setup magento 2.1 from existing project](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187303/how-to-setup-magento-2-1-from-existing-project)

I have redone and imported the root files multiple times using this command.

```
ssh root@IP tar cf - /var/www/html/magento2 > /var/www/html/magento2.tgz
```

I followed these instructions when I moved my project:

- [How to move magento shop to another server](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22120/how-to-move-magento-shop-to-another-server)
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/upgrade-with-plugin.html